# Creating Random Number row Vector within range ans sum should be equal to M

Tags: matlab, random, numbers

I am very confused with simple MATLAB random number generation problem. I know it looks silly and basic level some how but I have tried google before but could not find any useful solution.

I have bounds like this

```
  Lb = [150,100,150]; %in MW
  Ub = [600,400,200]; %in MW
  Pd = 850;   %in MW
```

I want to create a random guess which sum will be equal to Pd and which should be within limits of Lower and Upper Bounds.

I am able to generate row vector within limits like this

```
        `u0=Lb+(Ub-Lb).*rand(1,d);`
```

and I know that to generate random number which sum would be equal to Pd can be obtained like this

```
u0=rand(1,d);
u0=u0/sum(u0);
u0=u0*Pd;
```

How to combine both effect in single random number generation. 
thanks

Comment: The typical way to make `sum(random_number_vector) == X` is to generate `n-1` random numbers and make the n-th random number equal to `X=sum(n-1 numbers)` . As to fitting within bounds, your question is unclear.  Do you want **each** value to be within the bounds?

Comment: Yes, Each value to be within bound range, as I want 3 values which sum should be equal to Pd and values range be within Lb and Ub matrix range limit

Comment: If I've understood your question, if you remove `u0=rand(1,d);` the two pieces of code already generate the numbers you are looking for.

Comment: If I understand you well, you want 3 values, so that the first one is between `Lb(1)` and `Ub(1)` and so on, and so that they sum up to `Pd`?

Comment: Exactally, @BillBokeey

Answer (score 2):

This is not as easy as it looks, as the bound will put some extra constraints on the problem :

**1) Your current solution :**

Your corrected code (As stated by @il_raffa in the comments) would look like :

```
Lb = [150,100,150]; %in MW
Ub = [600,400,200]; %in MW
Pd = 850;   %in MW
d=3;

u0=Lb+(Ub-Lb).*rand(1,d) % Output before normalization

u0=(u0/sum(u0))*Pd % Output after normalization
```

**Outputs :**

```
u0 =

  516.6257  371.7376  156.3493 % Before Normalization

u0 =

  420.3374  302.4535  127.2091 % After Normalization
```

As you can see, the sum of the elements of `u0` was quite bigger than `Pd`, *and* the third value in `u0` was pretty close from the lower bound. Thus after Normalization the third value in `u0` is lower than the corresponding lower bound.

A similar problem will happen with the solution @CarlWitthoft presents in the comments. It is possible that after generating `n-1` random numbers, the n-th number making the sum be equal to `Pd` would not lie within the bound range.

**2) Conclusion :**

The only way to do it in my opinion is to **iterate until you find a solution**, so it would be something along the lines of :

```
Lb = [150,100,150]; %in MW
Ub = [600,400,200]; %in MW
Pd = 850;   %in MW
d=3;

u0=[Inf Inf Inf];

while(~all((u0>Lb).*(u0<Ub))) 

u0=Lb+(Ub-Lb).*rand(1,d);

u0=(u0/sum(u0))*Pd;

end
```

**Output :**

```
u0 =

533.9384  134.6124  181.4492
```

Comment: Why iterate when you can generate a random number in `[0,1]` and scale it to the desired range via a linear transform?

Comment: Because either you scale it to the desired range, either you scale it so that the sum equals Pd, not necessarily both (in my opinion)

Comment: Ahh, I see.   I was hoping there was a simple way to scale then shift,  but that additional constraint will lead to a nonlinear map.